# click on button which appears sometime on screen using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am working automating website which generates quotations for mixer selection, sometimes for some parameters list of mixers suggested is more than 5 then Next button appears below the list. This button shown on the screen only when mixer list is more than 5.

below code I am using to save screenshot of the page and I want to screenshot of page which will come after click on Next button whenever it is available.

```
name = str(worksheet.cell_value(1,1))+"_"+str(worksheet.cell_value(1,2))+"_"+str(worksheet.cell_value(1,3))+\
   "_"+str(worksheet.cell_value(1,4))+str(worksheet.cell_value(1,5))+".png"
driver.save_screenshot("D:\Automation\Pycharm_project\MRMix\Screenshots\%s"%name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say if next button is displayed, then need to click on it and need to take screenshot. You can simply try like below (in java)

you can have small method to return true or false depends on next button display

```
    boolean isNextDisplay=false;

    try {

        if(driver.findElement(By.id("nextButton")).isDisplayed()==true) {
            isNextDisplay=true;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("next button not displayed");
    }
```

depends on display, click on next button and take screenshot.

```
   if(isNextDisplay==true) {
        //click on next button
        //take screenshot
    }
```

instead of methods, you can straightway write it. in Try >>If >> click and take screenshot

Comment: Hi Murali, Thanks for the reply. I am using python so could you please write python code for the same?